# how to find if a string has more than 5 integer inside itself in php

Tags: php, regex

how can I find if a string has more than 4 integer inside itself.
this is just for showing whether has an integer or not.

```
<?php
  $a='ldfjdls55';
  $result = preg_match("/\\d/", $a);
 if($result> 0)
    echo true;
 else
    echo false;
?>
```

so it prints `1` that means true;
if I have `$a=sdfjlfs47'`, it prints `0` , false, because it has less than 5 integer .
thx in advance.

Comment: 1) Put your regex inside https://regex101.com and see what exactly you match with that regex. 2) Please open the manual page about `preg_match()` and see what exactly that function returns.

Comment: `\\d` does not match digits. it matches a backslash followed by a `d`. ``\\`` is an escaped backslash.

Comment: @MarcB: No, `\\d` matches a digit.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no. it doesn't. Try it

Comment: @MarcB: Sure - https://ideone.com/lZ380y. It is **PHP**.

Comment: @Steven, you want to check if there are 5 or more consecutive digits? Then use `preg_match("/\\d{5,}/", $a);` (or `preg_match("/\d{5,}/", $a);`, it's the same)

Comment: Ok. That is just totally bizarre. ``\\`` is an escaped backslash, which makes it NOT an escape character. It should **NOT** work...

Comment: @MarcB: Both in single and double quoted string literals in PHP, you need to use double ``\`` to denote a literal ``\``.

Comment: Then why does `"/\d/"` ALSO match the integer? If you HAVE to escape the backslash, then that should match only the literal character `d`, NOT a digit.

Comment: Of all the people I'd argue with about regex @WiktorStribiżew is literally the last.  Look at his answer history.

Comment: @MarcB: It is just because PHP is too lenient with unknown escape sequences. Not like JavaScript. More, `"/\b/"` will match a word bounsary in PHP, not a backspace char  (as it would in Python or JS with `"\b"`).

Comment: but `\d` is NOT an unknown escape sequence. it's part of the PCRE syntax. just... bizzare.

Comment: and the `\b` stuff is at least [documented](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php): `In addition, inside a character class, the sequence "\b" is interpreted as the backspace character (hex 08). Outside a character class it has a different meaning (see below).`

Comment: So `Test11111`, should match because it has 5 integers. Should `1test1111` also match? That has 5 integers, but not consecutive.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: yeah, you were right. figured it out. See CW "answer" below. PHP parser thing, not a regex issue at all.

Comment: In PCRE `\b` is a backspace character only inside a character class. Outside a class, `\b` is a word boundary, and the backspace is `\x08`

Comment: Comments have this question off track. The issue is that `preg_match("/\\d/", $a)` is only checking for a number. So if `$a` has any amount of numbers it will be true.

Comment: Character 5 to 9 is `[5-9]`, Regular expressions can't match integers, only code's of characters. If there is code you're interested in, use the hex construct `\x##` to detect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think is this that you want :

```
<?php
  $a='ld2f82jdls55';
  $result = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$a);
  $strresult= strlen($result);
  $int = intval($strresult);
if ($int > 4) {
    echo 1;
} else {
    echo 0;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
$result = preg_match("/[0-9]{5}/", $a);
```

Or with your pattern:

```
$result = preg_match("/\d{5}/", $a);
```

`{5,}` means 5 or more, but you really only need `{5}` since you are just looking for match or no match.  If there are 5 then there are 5 or more.

Comment: My reading of the question, is the OP is looking for +4 integers in the whole string, not necessarily consecutive.

Answer (score 0):

`preg_match` doesn't return a count of matches.

> preg_match() returns 1 if the pattern matches given subject, 0 if it does not, or FALSE if an error occurred.

-http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

You could use `preg_replace` for that.

```
$a='ld2f82jdls55';
$result = preg_replace("/\d/","",$a, -1, $count);
echo $count;
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as a CW to follow up on the comment chain above:

Allright, I've had my morning coffee. It's not a PCRE thing, it's a PHP parser thing. Escapes on character which are NOT string metacharacters will be passed through as is. Since `\d` is not a string metachar like (say) `\n` would be, the pattern STAYS `\d` whether you have `\d` or `\\d` in there:

For `'` strings, non-string metachar:

```
php > $pat = '/\d/'; echo strlen($pat), ' :: ' , $pat;
4 :: /\d/
php > $pat = '/\\d/'; echo strlen($pat), ' :: ' , $pat;
4 :: /\d/
php > $pat = '/\\\d/'; echo strlen($pat), ' :: ' , $pat;
5 :: /\\d/
```

For `"` strings:

```
php > $pat = "/\d/"; echo strlen($pat), ' :: ' , $pat;
4 :: /\d/
php > $pat = "/\\d/"; echo strlen($pat), ' :: ' , $pat;
4 :: /\d/
php > $pat = "/\\\d/"; echo strlen($pat), ' :: ' , $pat;
5 :: /\\d/
```

And then for "known" string metachars:

```
php > $pat = '/\n/'; echo strlen($pat), ' :: ' , $pat;
4 :: /\n/
php > $pat = '/\\n/'; echo strlen($pat), ' :: ' , $pat;
4 :: /\n/

php > $pat = "/\\n/"; echo strlen($pat), ' :: ' , $pat;
4 :: /\n/

php > $pat = "/\n/"; echo strlen($pat), ' :: ' , $pat;
3 :: /     <--note the literal line break that occurred here.
/          <--and the string length has dropped to '3'
```